# Internally sorting a class that inherits from a vector of pointers to a user defined object (C++)

Tags: c++

So I defined a class on C++ that inherits from a vector of pointers:

```
class SuperBinList : public std::vector<SuperBin*>{

public:
  SuperBinList();
  SuperBinList(const std::vector<SuperBin*>& superBinList);
  virtual ~SuperBinList();

  SuperBinList& operator += (SuperBin* superBin);
  SuperBinList& operator += (const SuperBinList& superBin);

  void sortByZbi(const double sys);
  void sortBySoverB() const;

};
```

The SuperBin class itself is defined as:

```
class SuperBin{

public:
  SuperBin(const VI index, const double nSig, const double nBkg, const VS mPerpLabel, const VS rIsrLabel, const VS visLabel);
  virtual ~SuperBin();

  VI getIndex();
  double getNsig();
  double getNbkg();
  double getSoverB();
  double getBinZbi(const double sys);

  VS getMperpLabel();
  VS getRisrLabel();
  VS getVisLabel();

  SuperBin* tryMerge(SuperBin* superBin, double sys);

private:

  VI index_;
  double nSig_;
  double nBkg_;
  double sOverB_;
  VS mPerpLabel_;
  VS rIsrLabel_;
  VS visLabel_;

};
```

Now the problem I'm having is that I want the SuperBinList class to be able to sort itself in descending order in terms of any of the (double type) members of the SuperBin class (such as sOverB). For this I tried the following method using a lambda function:

```
void SuperBinList::sortBySoverB() const{

  std::sort(this->begin(), this->end(), [](const SuperBin* lhs, const SuperBin* rhs){
      return lhs->getSoverB() < rhs->getSoverB();});
}
```

The top error I'm getting is:

```
error: passing 'const SuperBin' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
       return lhs->getSoverB() < rhs->getSoverB();});
```

Which, as I understood from similar threads, has to do with the const specifiers. However, I'm still not sure what it is that I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please pardon my ignorance as I am a physics PhD and not a computer scientist.

Comment: `this` points to a const object in `sortBySoverB`. Therefore `this->begin()` returns a const iterator, i.e. one that cannot be used to modify the values in the vector. `std::sort` requires a iterator that can be used to write the elements though... Also of course non-`const` member functions cannot be called using a pointer to `const`. Even if the vector is `const`, the elements are still pointers to non-`const` and depending in this scenario you need to make the the lambda parameters to be pointers to non-const (or better make `getSoverB()` `const`).

Comment: In other words, remove the `const` from `void sortBySoverB() const;` - it doesn't make logical sense to have it there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your `SuperBinList::sortBySoverB()` function defined as const, which means it is not allowed to modify `SuperBinList`, and
`this` will have the type `const SuperBinList *`, rather than `SuperBinList *`

Similarly, your lambda is define with const pointers `const SuperBin* lhs`, meaning you can only call const functions.

Change your function definitions to `void SuperBinList::sortBySoverB() {}` and `double getSoverB() const {}`, and it should compile. (Generally member functions should be marked const if they are read-only operations like getters).